# Is there in C++ something similar to weak reference in Java?

Tags: c++

Is there in C++ something similar to weak reference in Java ?
I have list of objects in game (class Soldier, list is std::list* enemy), where I hold list of visible enemy soldiers. Every my soldier can have pointer to enemy Soldier ( Soldier* target; inside class). What I need when other mine soldiers killed enemy soldier (then killed soldier is removed from enemy list) I want that all my soldiers which have that pointer of soldier as target to have now null, because it is deleted.
I can solve this with soldier's id and in every loop to check is there enemy soldier with same id but it seems like to brute force. Can I solve this on more elegant way( I cannot use c++11?

```
class Soldier{
Soldier* target;

public:
// other functions
void shootAtTarget();
};
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr

Comment: Regarding C++11; IIRC std::weak_ptr is included in tr1 as well. Other than that you have boost::weak_ptr. If all else fails I would look at the boost code and be inspired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that there is no exact behavioral equivelent.  Java's weak reference concept really relies on there being a garbage collector, and managed memory in general.  In C++, a pointer is just a memory location, so something else needs to "track" the lifecycle of an object.

In Java, all memory is being managed by the garbage collector, so there is a mechanism to know when an object is removed.  In C++, this doesn't happen without library usage, since the pointer itself is really just a number.

You should be able to use a [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) (or `tr1::weak_ptr`) to get similar behavior.  This requires storing your object in a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of a raw pointer, though (which is a good idea anyways).

Given that you cannot use C++11, you can use [`boost::weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) with [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) instead of the C++ standard libraries.

Comment: He said that he can't use C++11.

Comment: @SubSevn I provided an alternative, too

Comment: [It's not STL, it's the C++ Standard Library](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use `Observer design pattern` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern .

Answer (score 1):

If each soldier has a list of soldiers which target that soldier, you can just clear their targets when the soldier dies. You can also make the targeting soldiers try to acquire another target.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't user weak_ptr (as suggested in the other answer) I would just suggest checking if the target is dead (or deallocated/null) in your other Soldiers, and acting accordingly (which is kind of what the weak_ptr would've given you from a logical perspective, except you have to do the check explicitly).

Unless you can move to C++11 (a good idea).  OR use the boost variant, as mentioned in another answer.